# How to use JFrog pipelines build image from local artifactory?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

Everytime i run my build in jfrog pipelines, i see that the build image is being pulled from releases-docker.jfrog.io. Would like to instead pull the image from my own artifactory instance to reduce time.

Here is my sample test pipeline:

```
pipelines:
  - name: testSimple_1
    steps:
      - name: testSimple
        type: Bash
        configuration:
          runtime:
            type: image
            image:
              custom:
                name: releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/pipelines-u18node
                tag: "16"
        execution:
          onExecute:
            - echo "executing step ..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following steps to achieve this,

1. Create a remote artifactory repo in your instance by pointing the url to https://releases-docker.jfrog.io/

```
  Sample input,
    Repository Key : myreleasesremote
    URL : https://releases-docker.jfrog.io/
```

2. Create a pipelines integration of type "Docker Registry" with required input,

```
  Sample input,
    Name : myregistry
    url : https://<your_docker_registry_dns>/myreleasesremote
    User Name : <your_artifactory_username>
    Password : <your_artifactory_apikey>
```

3. Update the pipelines source yaml to point to your new remote docker repo,

```
pipelines:
  - name: testSimple_1
    steps:
      - name: testSimple
        type: Bash
        configuration:
          runtime:
            type: image
            image:
              custom:
                name: <your_docker_registry_dns>/myreleasesremote/jfrog/pipelines-u18node
                tag: "16"
                sourceRepository: myreleasesremote
                registry: myregistry
```